# Upload de Imagens Não funciona

Tags: android, apache-cordova, app, cordova-plugin

Estou a usar `cordova` pra modo a passar a minha aplicação `WEB` para `Android`.
Na minha plicaçao Web faço upload de imagens usando as tags basicas do HTML `<ipnut type='file' >`.
quando instalo a aplicação no `Android` ja não consigo fazer upload de images.

Alguém ja passou por uma experience igual ?

Comment: Olá amigo você está usando IONIC 2?

Answer (score 1):

Existe uma diferença, primeiro precisamos entender com o que está trabalhando, mas seguindo.

Você pode sim ter um `<input type="file">` para o upload da foto, mas recomendo que utilize o `Plugin` da [Camera](https://github.com/cordova-plugin-camera-preview/cordova-plugin-camera-preview).

Você pode usar o [FileTransfer](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/) para enviar a imagem para o servidor.

Acessando a `Galeria`

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto, function(message) {
 alert('Erro ao enviar');
 }, {
 quality: 100,
 destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
 sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
 });
```

Upload para o servidor.

```
var ft = new FileTransfer();
 ft.upload(imageURI, "SUA URL", function(result){
 console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
 }, function(error){
 console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
 }, options);
```